# Windows Azure - The StorageClient framework could not be loaded

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have debugged and discovered that the StorageClient framework could not be loaded... I'm getting this error Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.1.0.0 should be in a very low version of Azure SDK. Currently it should be 1.7 along with SDK 1.8 and 2.0 alone with NuGet package.

You can install the latest SDK to get this solved. Alternatively you might need to mark this assembly as Copy Local = true so that it can be uploaded to azure.

Answer (score 0):

I did delet the StorageClient 1.0 from my project and add the StorageClient  1.7